How many times it is done
I asked this question before but now I will try to be more accurate. It's common that when we give the exact number of attemtps or how many times we did something. We use simple tenses instead of continuous ones. For instance
I have worked 3 times
I had worked 5 times
I played 10 times
How does it work with the future? We could certainly use present continuous with an exact number of attempts thus this tense is used to show plans "I'm playing 4 times tomorrow" is a valid sentence. What about other expressions? Let me provide examples

I'm sure to be playing three times this afternoon

I'm sure to play  three times this afternoon

She's certain to be doing it 3 times  this morning

She's certain to do it 3 times this morning

She must be playing 4 times during the meeting

She must play 4 times during the meeting


Can you share your thoughts about these sentences? Are all of these continuous forms wrong or unnatural since the exact number of attempts is provided?

I've explained before that an attempt is when you try to do something - "She made three attempts before she succeeded". Also, play is an odd choice of verb to use in your examples. Does it mean 'play a tennis match', 'play a piece on a musical instrument' or something else? How do you play during a meeting?

To do something a number of times can be used basically with any tense. She must be playing right now because I don't know where she is.

I don't find any of your sentences particularly natural, partly because of the odd choice of words.
This website gives some examples of using the continuous tense to predict the future. It says that one of the ways we use it is to say that something is likely but not certain.

[My favourite footballer] is sure to be scoring lots of goals this season.

We can sometimes use it of something that is planned to happen.

Mary will be singing three songs in the concert tonight.


Counting activities can be ambiguous

(INCORRECT) I had worked 5 times.

This could mean "I had 5 jobs", or "I worked at one job for 5 days". You can't use the simple-tense counting because it's unclear. Your examples sound better if we modify them to be countable.

I have worked the night shift 3 times.
She must play the song 4 times during the meeting.
She will perform 4 times during the show.

The number of times one performs is sufficiently clear without clarification, since a performance usually has a clear beginning and end.
Progressive vs simple

She will be performing 3 times

Is not incorrect, but it's often unnecessary.

She will perform 3 times during the show

Is simpler and generally better. Either is usable, though.
Modal verb/phrase choice:
80% of the time, use one of going to, will, has to, got to, gets to, or needs to.
Your examples are correct but they aren't natural-sounding.

(ORIGINAL) I'm sure to play three times this afternoon
(ORIGINAL) She's certain to do it 3 times this morning

If the certainty isn't in doubt, use will/going to. Or have to when it's an obligation, and get to if it's an opportunity. If the certainty is in doubt, sure to/certain to are still uncommon.

(CASUAL) I'm going to play 3 times today, for sure.
(MORE FORMAL) She will certainly play 3 times today.

For example 5/6:

(ORIGINAL) She must play 4 times during the meeting.

"Must" is very formal. I'd use has to or got to, even in writing. For example, "I must go" sounds like an extremely dated goodbye, but "I gotta go" or "I have to go" are common casual phrases, and "I need to go" is a bit more formal.

(CASUAL) She has to play 4 times during the meeting.
(MORE FORMAL) She needs to play 4 times during the meeting.

